# passing the value of dropdownlist into gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist populated by my database, below is my code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsNames" 
    DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsNames" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbProfilesConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT Lname+', '+Fname AS Name,Id FROM tblProfile">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Beside my Dropdownlist, I have a button and below I have a Gridview, what I want to achieve is whenever I select one of the name in my Dropdownlist, then when I click the button the name should be added in gridview. I am using asp.net with c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Try this code.

```
DataTable dttable = new DataTable();
DataColumn column;
DataRow row; 

column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
column.ColumnName = "EmpName";
dttable.Columns.Add(column);

row = table.NewRow();   
row["EmpName"] = DropDownList1.SelectedText;
dttable.Rows.Add(row);

Gridview1.DataSource = dttable;
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

Before Adding next record please maintain datatable in Session or View state.And play with that.

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

you can add new item to your gridview data source with selected dropdownlist name, and then bind gridview with new datasource.