# Populate GridView from DropDownList & Button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a page which has a dropdownlist populated with a name (`Text`) and ID (`Value`), and a button on my page.  What hoping to do is when an item is selected in the drop down list (DDL), and the button is clicked, that a row gets added to a `GridView` which contains the Text value of the DDL in one column, and an editable field in another column (blank text by default).

Here is the markup for my `GridView`, `DropDownList` and `Button`.

```
              <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdSelectedProduct" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="grdSelectedProduct_OnRowDataBound" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
                                <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product" ReadOnly="False"/>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ReadOnly="False"/>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>


           <asp:Button ID="btnAddProduct" runat="server" Text="Add Product" ValidationGroup="valproduct"
                                OnClick="btnAddProduct_OnClick" CssClass="btnAdd" CausesValidation="true" />


          <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlProducts" DataTextField="description"
                                DataValueField="alphaKey" CssClass="select" />
```

Thus far I've been able to add a row to the grid with the following hardcoded values, however this doesn't make the second column editable and it adds only 1 row.  If I click the button again it will remove the values.

```
    protected void btnAddProduct_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        DataRow dataRow;
        dataTable.Columns.Add("ProductName");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Description");  // This can be editted by the user
        if (grdSelectedCountries.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < grdSelectedCountries.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (grdSelectedProduct.Rows[i].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                    dataRow["ProductName"] = "MyTestProduct";
                    dataRow["Description"] = "";
                    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                    dataRow["ProductName"] = "MyTestProduct";
                    dataRow["Description"] = "";
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }

        grdSelectedProduct.DataSource = dataTable;
        grdSelectedProduct.DataBind();
    }
```

one of the things I'm concerned about is if I put code in the `btnAddProduct_OnClick` event would that work server side?  Would the client side properly update?

Please could I have some guidance on how to achieve my goals?

Also I realise there is the likes of this q & a: [passing the value of dropdownlist into gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806780/passing-the-value-of-dropdownlist-into-gridview), however that asks that the datatable is persisted in `Session` which I would like to avoid.

Comment: use template field instead of boundfield in your description column and place a textbox in item template of templatefield

Comment: event would definitely execute on server side sir, if you want to execute it on client side you should use JQuery instead.

Comment: @TinkuRana how would I get around having multiple text boxes?  This will, eventually, be a multi row grid.  I also need to get the data from these boxes later.